# i want to have a single column containing different values for each month

Tags: excel

I have created a table in excel for keeping the leave records of staff. I created a scroll bar to scroll to a different month. I have added an extra column named "leave this month" which shows how many days a person has taken leave. but when I scroll to a different month (for example from January to February) the column's data stays the same. I want it to have different data for different months. for example for January it is 3 days, for February it is 4 days and... I want different values in the same cell for different months.(when I scroll to a different month the value should change) do you guys know how to do that?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRRo5.jpg)

```
 Sub showcalendar()
 LeaveTracker.Columns("C:NJ").Hidden = True
 LeaveTracker.Range(Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 - 28),Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 + 2)).Hidden = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using VBA? (I guess so because of your custom scrollbar). Post you code.

Comment: Please, not like that!! Edit your question and present the code in a nicely formatted way.

Comment: someone told me that it is possible using the OFFSET formula, but I dont know how to do that

Comment: Again, post your code.

Comment: The code is there. I also attached a screenshot

Comment: Assuming `B3` has the month number, add the month numbers in row4(example `C4:AG4 = 1` (Jan), `AH4:BL4 =2` (Feb)) and use `SUMIF`, `NK8 = SUMIF($C$4:$NJ$4,$B$3,C8:NJ8)`

Comment: sorry, but I didnt get the part about row 4,

Comment: I would have done this in a different way. The question is: are you willing to consider a different implementation?

Comment: @FDavidov. Of course, I would be glad to hear!

Comment: OK. I'll post my approach as an answer, but I'll only be able to do it later on today. Hope you can wait.

Comment: that's ok. I will wait.

Comment: My approach posted (verbal description only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach I would use:

1. Define a spreadsheet with 31 X 12 columns (each group of 31 columns would represent a month, even for those cases when the month has 28/29/30 days); this spreadsheet will be use as the storage of the raw data (i.e. presence/absence of a person each day of the year),
2. A second spreadsheet to be use for display will have the cells linked to the first one with an horizontal offset (to the right) to be calculated as 31 * (month_number - 1); as such, when looking at the information of March, the offset would be 62 columns to the right.
3. Your scrollbar would run from 1 to 12 and set the value of the month (which would then be used to calculate the offset.

In this way, you don't need to copy-paste anything and, instead, you have a sliding "window" that runs right and left over your raw data sheet.

Hoe this description is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have 365 columns for each day of the year. On row 4(or wherever suitable) add the month number i.e. for the first 31 columns, cells will have 01 in row4. For the next 28 columns cells in row 4 will have 02 and so on.

then in NK8, the formula to be entered should be

```
SUMIF($C$4:$NJ$4,$B$3,C8:NJ8)
```

which you can drag down for each person. B3 ahs the current month number you are viewing. The formula basically sums only those cells whose corresponding cell in row4 matches the month number in B3.

Here is a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFZ9K8Mthn2SGDT2TVRTyKu9-qKV8NGtuJw4PJH-cN4/edit?usp=sharing) example.